# How do I create an outline of the HTML tag structure on the page using Nokogiri?

Tags: html, ruby, html-parsing, nokogiri

I am trying to create an outline of the tag structure of an HTML page using Nokogiri that I can use as an indicator whether an html page's content has changed.

To do this, basically I want to strip all the text out, and just have the HTML tags remaining (without attributes).

The idea is to use this as a sketch of the page, one of a few I use, to see if the page has changed.

When I'm done, I want the "sketch" to look roughly like

```html
<html><head></head><body><div></div><p><div></div></p></body></html>
```

So that it can be compared against revisions to see if the page structure has changed.

There are a ton of examples of how to parse the dom in Nokogiri. But, how about just listing it?

Any thoughts anyone?

Comment: The DOM is a pretty basic tree structure: nodes contain data (attributes, text) and have child nodes.  Have you thought about how you might serialize (list) that structure?  Think about how you might do that and consider updating your question with what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would do:

```
class Nokogiri::XML::Node

  def to_sketch
    children.find_all(&:element?).map(&:to_sketch).join
  end
end

class Nokogiri::XML::Element
  def to_sketch
    "<#{name}>#{super}</#{name}>"
  end
end
```

**EDIT** An example

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://google.com')).to_sketch
```

Returns:

```
"<html><head><meta></meta><title></title><script></script><style></style><script></script></head><body><textarea></textarea><div><div><nobr><b></b><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a><u></u></a></nobr></div><div><nobr><span></span><span></span><span><a></a></span><a></a><a></a></nobr></div><div></div><div></div></div><center><br></br><div><a><img></img></a><br></br><br></br></div><form><table><tr><td></td><td><input></input><input></input><input></input><div><input></input></div><br></br><span><span><input></input></span></span><span><span><input></input></span></span></td><td><a></a><a></a></td></tr></table></form><div><br></br><div><font><a></a><a></a><a></a></font><br></br><br></br></div></div><div></div><span><center><div><div><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a></div></div><p><a></a></p></center></span><div></div><div><script></script></div><script></script><script></script></center></body></html>"
```