# Get HTML structure using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, html-parsing, nokogiri

My task is to get the HTML structure of the document without data. From:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello!</title>
  </head>
  <body id="uniq">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to get:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body id="uniq">
    <h1></h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

There are a number of ways to extract data with Nokogiri, but I couldn't find a way perform the reverse task.

UPDATE:
The solution found is the combination of two answers I received:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("test.html"))
  doc.at_css("html").traverse do |node|
    if node.text?
      node.remove
    end
  end
    puts doc
```

The output is exactly the one I want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create an outline of the HTML tag structure on the page using Nokogiri?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176094/how-do-i-create-an-outline-of-the-html-tag-structure-on-the-page-using-nokogiri)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Traverse](http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#M000308) the document. For each node, delete what you don't want. Then write out the document.

Remember that Nokogiri can change the document. [Doc](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/modifying_an_html_xml_document.html)

Comment: Thanks, Larry. I read the page from url. You would suggest to write the whole page source to the file and manipulate from there?

Comment: You mean for loading the doc at the start? You can load direct from an URL into nokogiri. See [doc](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html)

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want to remove all the text nodes. You can do this like so:

```
doc.xpath('//text()').remove
puts doc
```

Comment: doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("trial.html"))
puts doc.xpath('//text()').remove
gives the following result : Hello!   Hello world! It is the opposite of what I want..